# RenderFragment causing all same type components to update

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have run into a bit of an issue writing a Blazor Server Component. I have a custom component which is used multiple times on the same page. When a property on either of the components is changed, both components are re-rendered / updated (if a `RenderFragment` is used in the component).  **Why is this? How do I fix it so that only the property on the correct component renders the update for that component only, and not updating all the other components?**

This only happens when a using a `RenderFragment`.  Removing the `RenderFragment`, and `@ChildContent` from the component fixes the issue.

I have created a simple example that demonstrates the issue.

**page.razor**

```
@page "/"

<div>
    <button @onclick="OnClick_Update_1">Update 1</button>
    <button @onclick="OnClick_Update_2">Update 2</button>
</div>
<h3>Component 1</h3>
<MyComponent PlayNice="DoUpdate_1">ABC</MyComponent>

<h3>Component 2</h3>
<MyComponent PlayNice="DoUpdate_2">DEF</MyComponent>

@code{
    private bool DoUpdate_1 { get; set; } = false;
    private bool DoUpdate_2 { get; set; } = false;

    private void OnClick_Update_1(){
        DoUpdate_1 = true;
    }

    private void OnClick_Update_2() {
        DoUpdate_2 = true;
    }
}
```

**MyComponent.razor**

```
<p class="@_class">@ChildContent - @DateTime.UtcNow</p>

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool PlayNice { get; set; } = false;
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; } = default!;

    private string _class { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override void OnParametersSet() {
        _class = string.Empty;
        if (PlayNice)
            _class += "abcdef";
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }

}
```

A working example is available here: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/facmehiz
(Alternate clicking the buttons - both components will update)

An example without the RenderFragment: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/0w11bbxw
(is the result I want, but I want to use a RenderFragment)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet illustrates how to render each component at a time... Each time you click on "Update 1", the first instance of `MyComponent` is re-render. Each time you click on "Update 2", the second instance of `MyComponent` is re-render. Copy and test...

### MyComponent.razor

```
<p class="@_class">@ChildContent - @DateTime.UtcNow</p>

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool PlayNice { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> PlayNiceChanged { get; set; }

   
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    private string _class { get; set; }

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        return PlayNice;
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        _class = string.Empty;
        if (PlayNice)
        {
            PlayNiceChanged.InvokeAsync(false);

            _class += "abcdef";
        }

    }

}
```

### Index.razor

```
@page "/"

<div>
    <button @onclick="OnClick_Update_1">Update 1</button>
    <button @onclick="OnClick_Update_2">Update 2</button>
</div>
<h3>Component 1</h3>
<MyComponent @bind-PlayNice="DoUpdate_1">ABC</MyComponent>

<h3>Component 2</h3>
<MyComponent @bind-PlayNice="DoUpdate_2">DEF</MyComponent>

@code{
    private bool DoUpdate_1 { get; set; } 
    private bool DoUpdate_2 { get; set; } 

    private void OnClick_Update_1()
    {
        DoUpdate_1 = true;
        
    }

    private void OnClick_Update_2()
    {
        DoUpdate_2 = true;
    
    }
}
```